# Trouble connecting to Git server (bitbucket.org) via Win 10 Git Bash

Tags: bash, git, github, bitbucket, putty

I had to restart my machine but things were working before hand. I was using Git Bash with SSH and hoses on Win 10 to connect to BitBucket which was fine.

I then had to also connect with Git Bash (another instance) to GitHub. This required Putty and Pagent to get setup.

No I try to connect to BitBucket and get this:

```
git pull origin mybranch
FATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Is there a simple way to have both working in different shells?

I tried to do a plink.exe to bitbucket.org but that made things worse.

Comment: Have you consider https://desktop.github.com/ for github? This way you will have no intereference among both.

Comment: Or use https and the git credential manager for windows to handle the auth jumble for you.

Comment: I cannot use GH desktop since it is a specific GH enterprise that doesn't authenticate

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a simple way to have both working in different shells?

Yes. You can use any single method (from both) for connecting to HG|BB. Just select preferred way (ssh + ssh-agent OR pageant) and perform needed steps according to relevant docs